# Does the 'No-Superdeterminism' assumption of the 2020 Wigner's friend experiment excl backwards/block-wise/holistic consistency & limited nonlocality?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, quantum-interpretations, determinism, schroedingers-cat

In "[A strong no-go theorem on the Wigner’s friend paradox](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-020-0990-x)" authors conclude that one of three possible options is necessary for reconciling quantum physics with more classical physical reality, describing one of the three options, abandoning "No-Superdeterminism", as follows:

> The No-Superdeterminism assumption is a formalization of the assumption of ‘freedom of choice’ used in derivations of Bell inequalities. It is the assumption that the experimental settings can be chosen freely, that is, uncorrelated with any relevant variables prior to that choice.

and

> Any set of events on a space-like hypersurface is uncorrelated  with any set of freely chosen actions subsequent to that space-like hypersurface. In the EWFS, this implies that c and d are independent of the choices x and y

It looks like with this "No-Superdeterminism"-assumption they aren't considering mechanisms by which experimental settings and results somehow "evolve" to be consistent and instead only consider determinism-related mechanisms by which the Universe predetermines the experimental settings and results (by being entirely deterministic since its start).

More specific exemplary descriptions of such mechanisms:

- mechanisms that make "past" experimental settings consistent with "present" results *(simplified way to imagine this: a thousand parallel worlds with different courses of the experiment with the or a "consistent" world "surviving" after the experiment's conclusion and measurement of the result)*
- mechanisms that are only completely deterministic for a sub-domain/-process of the Universe that is relevant to the experiment *(simplified way to imagine this: when the experiment is launched all influences of all variables influencing the experiment become entangled with the experiment's settings and results in a way that the relevant choices and results are consistent)*
- mechanisms by which, as in the earlier point, processes may evolve in "block"-wise fashion *(simplified way to imagine this: no true past or future exists within the block but only a consistent reality that is consistent more holistically at the scale of the entire "block" [being a e.g. temporal subpart of the Universe])*
- mechanisms on the scale of the Universe in its entirety or all its contents that ensure holistic consistency of results and experimental settings but (otherwise) retain basic locality (mostly at least) *(simplified way to imagine an "all its contents"-form: a function part of every particle which at the scale/domain of the experiment ensure consistency in terms of experimental-settings and results, but e.g. don't abolish locality beyond the domain of the experiment)*
- "Limited non-superdeterministic strong determinism" as described in "[Could a form of (temporally-limited non-superdeterministic) strong determinism resolve retrocausality in quantum theories?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/590773/could-a-form-of-temporally-limited-non-superdeterministic-strong-determinism-r)" (may match some of the earlier points)

These may overlap or even equate for different aspects or frames of reference of the same broad interpretative solution to quantum strangeness and Bell inequalities.

A main element underlying multiple of those is that the Universe is made of consistent "blocks", albeit probably without clear-cut borders and not (just) temporally even though it may be easiest to imagine it to be blocks of quantized spacetime with mechanisms that resolve for "consistency" between e.g. experimental settings and results that may appear "retrocausal" from out frame of reference. (I'm also interested in papers that explore similar ideas and calculations that may be relevant to it.)

I think an issue with the paper is that they present their Non-Superdeterminism-assumption only as an alternative to a form of *complete abandonment* of locality or realism, but not as a way to only have to e.g. *weaken* conceptions of locality instead of having to abandon it entirely.

**-> Would the roughly described proposed determinism-related mechanisms require only weaker or limited forms/concepts of locality (or realism) [i.e. instead of a more binary "yes/no" abandonment of locality] and would this mean that the three possible conclusions presented in the paper are missing something (and if not: why)?**

---

It may be that this whole issue and question can be resolved by their assumption of "if quantum evolution is controllable on the scale of an observer" (in the paper an observer is e.g. a photon's path) if that is not the case.

I'm not sure where the consistent histories approach would stand on this issue (maybe it would support one of those points or an additional option).

While I'm also interested in descriptions and conclusions of underlying calculations, this is a question about interpretations of experiments and present understanding of physics.